# How does ALB request health checks during ECS rolling update?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I deployed my service on ECS Fargate containers and using `rolling` deployment method. It has a ALB associate with the task. During deployment process, it will deploy a new container and mark the current one as `Inactive`. Then it destroys the current one after 300 seconds which is defined in ABL `Deregistration delay` field.

What I don't understand is that how many health check the ABL sends to the new instance? When both the old and new tasks running under the service, does both of them response the requests from load balancer or only the new task responses? If there is one unhealth response, will ABL roll back to the previous one?